# Quotient Group of Stabilizer and Larger (probably) Normal Subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, group-isomorphism, quotient-group

Let $G < Sym(\Omega)$ be a transitive group of degree $n$ and
$G_x$ a point-stabilizer. If $G = G_0 \triangleright G_1 \triangleright G_2 \triangleright \cdots$ be a composition chain of G. Then the subgroups $G_i \cap G_x$ form a subnormal chain $G_x  \trianglerighteq G_1\cap G_x \trianglerighteq G_2\cap G_x \cdots$.Now I would like to prove below 3 relations ([Source of the question, page 2, 3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.08266.pdf)):

i) $G/G_1 \geq  G_1 \cdot G_x/G_1$

ii) $G_i/G_{i+1} \geq  G_{i+1} \cdot (G_i \cap G_x)/G_{i+1} $

iii) $ G_{i+1} \cdot (G_i \cap G_x)/G_{i+1} \cong (G_i \cap G_x)/(G_{i+1} \cap G_x)$

It appears to me that $G_1$ could be larger normal subgroup than $G_x$, then how will we get the quotient group $G_x/G_1$, Similarly, $/G_{i+1}$ could be larger normal subgroup than $G_x$, in general I don't know hoe to begin with i) and ii).

In the case of iii), second isomorphism theorem could be used where $H/(H\cap K) \cong (HK)/K$, to get,

$ (G_i \cap G_x)/(G_{i+1} \cap G_x) \cong  (G_i \cap G_x) \cdot G_{i+1}/G_{i+1} $

**if we set,**

$H= (G_i \cap G_x),$

$K=G_{i+1},$

$(H\cap K)= (G_i \cap G_x) \cap G_{i+1}= (G_i \cap G_x)$, **since,** $G_i 
 \geq G_{i+1}$.

Is it correct? Also how do I prove i) and ii)?

Comment: In i), it's $(G_1G_x)/G_1$ (and same for ii)).

Comment: Your reasoning for iii) looks good to me. I believe you are overthinking the first two parts. Just note that if $G$ is a group with subgroup $H$ and normal subgroup $N$, then $HN = NH$ is a subgroup of $G$ and consequently $NH/N$ is a subgroup of $G/N$. Also, I guess $G_1 \cdot G_x / G_1$ is better written as $(G_1 \cdot G_x)/G_1$ or  $(G_x \cdot G_1)/G_1$ to prevent some of the confusions that could occur otherwise. Similarly for ii).

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch I can prove if $G$ is a group with subgroup $H$ and normal subgroup $N$, then $HN = NH$ is a subgroup of $G$  but don't know how to get,  $NH/N$ is a subgroup of $G/N$. Because, $NH/N$ is simply the  $H$, we know that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, but how we know that $H$ is a subgroup of $G/N$, would you please give some hint or refer to  any book's theorem?

Comment: Given the natural map $\pi : G \to G/N$ the image $\pi(H) = HN/N$ of any subgroup $H$ of $G$ is a subgroup of $G/N$. However, it is not true that $HN/N$ is 'simply' $H$, since you have $HN/N \cong H/N \cap H$, this is isomorphic to some quotient of $H$ but not to $H$ in general.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch Ah yes, you are correct,  the second isomorphism theorem tells that, but do you mean to write  natural projection (map) $\pi(H) = H/N$ (for subgroup $H$) or $\pi(HN) = HN/N$ (for subgroup $HN$), instead of $\pi(H) = HN/N$?

Comment: I actually meant to write $\pi(H) = HN/N$, maybe on some level it is an exercise to show that the image of an arbitrary subgroup $H$ under $\pi$ is $HN/N$. For the quotient $H/N$ to make any sense, you have to have $N \subseteq H$. Of course $\pi(H) = \pi(HN)$ since $\pi(N) = 1$ in $G/N$.